# Python in AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Private package dependencies

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to deploy a Python Flask application on beanstalk.

The application depends on external packages (e.g. [`geopy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy)) and internal packages (e.g. `adam_geography`).

The [manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_custom_container.html)

> Create a requirements.txt file and place it in the top-level directory
>   of your source bundle.

This would probably fetch [`geopy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) and its dependencies, but would not fetch `adam_geography` which is available from a custom repo inside my VPC.

**How do I specify/upload private, internal Python package dependencies in a Beanstalk application?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) copy internal Python package to server

2) use Pip's "editable installs" feature to install the private package:

```
pip install -e path/to/SomeProject
```

http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs

Comment: That would work for a single instance, but would it work for autoscaling?

Comment: @AdamMatan probably.  Autoscaling probably relies on a "golden image" which contains all your files.  In that case, omit step #1 -- it's even easier.

Comment: Can I create such a golden image from a Beanstalk instance?

Comment: I don't know.  Post another question to Stack Overflow giving more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Use ebextensions to specify custom commands you can use to download files on all your EC2 instances. These ebextensions can be used to run pip like @shavenwarthog suggested in his answer.
Create a directory called `.ebextensions` in your app source root directory. Inside this directory create a file with a `.config` extension say `01-custom-files.config`.
This file can contain custom unix commands you want to run on each EC2 instance.
You can run your own scripts here.

You can also use container_commands which are executed after unzipping your app source on the EC2 instance.

Read more about commands and container_commands here. You can also find examples here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands