# Configuring Elastic Beanstalk for SSH access to private git repo using Amazon Linux 2 hooks

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pipenv, amazon-linux-2

Suppose we have a custom Python package, called `shared_package`, in a private repository, hosted on github or bitbucket. Our private repository is configured for read-only access via SSH, as described e.g. [here for github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) and [here for bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-access-keys/).

Another one of our projects, aptly named `dependent_project`, depends on this `shared_package`, and needs to be deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB). Our environment uses the latest "Python on Amazon Linux 2" platform, and we use `pipenv` as package manager.

For various reasons, it would be most convenient for us to install `shared_package` directly from our online git repository, as described [here for pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/basics/#a-note-about-vcs-dependencies) and [here for pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/).
The `Pipfile` for our `dependent_project` looks like this:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
shared_package = {git = "ssh://bitbucket.org/our_username/shared_package.git", editable = true, ref = "2021.0"}

[dev-packages]
awsebcli = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

This works well on our local development systems, but when deploying `dependent_project` to Elastic Beanstalk, the `pipenv` installation fails with: `Permission denied (publickey)`.

This leads to the question:

**How to configure an Elastic Beanstalk environment, using [Amazon Linux 2 platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), so that `pipenv` can successfully install a package from a private online git repo, via SSH?**

Some pieces of the puzzle can be found in the following discussions, but these do not use Amazon Linux 2 platform hooks:

- [Setting up private Github access with AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Ruby container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13476138)
- [Setting up SSH keys for github private repo access on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43497663)
- [What is the recommended way to handle node.js private module dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22864010)
- [BitBucket: Host key verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40576718)
- [Grant S3 access to Elastic Beanstalk instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21653176)
- [How to deploy private python pip dependency with Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34727442)
- [Python in AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Private package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25367732)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Summary

Assume we have defined the following Elastic Beanstalk environment properties, and both the bitbucket public key file and our private key file have been uploaded to the specified S3 bucket:

```sh
S3_BUCKET_NAME="my_bucket"
REPO_HOST_NAME="bitbucket.org"
REPO_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME="bitbucket_public_key"
REPO_PRIVATE_KEY_NAME="my_private_key"
```

The configuration can then be accomplished using this hook in `.platform/hooks/prebuild`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# git is required to install our python packages directly from bitbucket
yum -y install git

# file paths (platform hooks are executed as root)
SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE="/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
SSH_CONFIG_FILE="/root/.ssh/config"
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE="/root/.ssh/$REPO_PRIVATE_KEY_NAME"

# remove any existing (stale) keys for our host from the known_hosts file
[ -f $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE ] && ssh-keygen -R $REPO_HOST_NAME

# read the (fresh) host key from S3 file and append to known_hosts file
aws s3 cp "s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$REPO_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME" - >> $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE

# copy our private key from S3 to our instance
aws s3 cp "s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$REPO_PRIVATE_KEY_NAME" $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE

# create an ssh config file to point to the private key file
tee $SSH_CONFIG_FILE <<HERE
Host $REPO_HOST_NAME
    User git
    Hostname $REPO_HOST_NAME
    IdentityFile $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
HERE

# file permissions must be restricted
chmod 600 $SSH_CONFIG_FILE
chmod 600 $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
```

Note this file requires execution permission (`chmod +x <file path>`).

### Detailed explanation

Read on for a detailed rationale.

#### Git

To access a `git` repository, our Elastic Beanstalk environment will need to have `git` installed.
This can be done in a platform hook using `yum` (`-y` assumes "yes" to every question):

```sh
yum -y install git
```

#### SSH keys

To set up an SSH connection between our Elastic Beanstalk (EB) instance and e.g. a bitbucket repository, we need three SSH keys:

- The **public** key for bitbucket.org, to verify that we are connecting to a trusted host.

  To obtain the public key for bitbucket.org, in a suitable format for `known_hosts`, we can use [ssh-keyscan](https://www.openssh.com/).
  To be on the safe side, we [should verify this key](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/251498) using a "trusted" source.
  In our case the best we can do is compare the public key fingerprint with the "official" one published on the [bitbucket](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-ssh-and-two-step-verification/) (or [github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints)) website.
  The fingerprint can be calculated from the public key using `ssh-keygen` e.g.

  ```sh
  ssh-keyscan -t rsa bitbucket.org | ssh-keygen -lf -
  ```
- The **private** key and **public** key for our repository.

  A key pair, consisting of private and public key, can be generated using `ssh-keygen`.
  The private key must be kept secret, the public key must be copied to the list of "access keys" for the bitbucket repository, as described in the [bitbucket docs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-access-keys/).
  Note that it is most convenient to create a key pair *without* passphrase, otherwise our script will need to handle the passphrase as well.

#### Storing the keys on AWS

The public bitbucket host key and our private repo key need to be available in the EB environment during deployment.
The *private* key is secret, so it should *not* be stored in the source code, nor should it be otherwise version controlled.

The most convenient option would be to store the key values as [EB environment properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console) (i.e. environment variables), because these are readily available during deployment.
In principle, this *can* be done, e.g. using `base64` encoding to store the multiline private key in a single line environment property.
However, the total size of all EB environment property keys and values combined is [limited to a mere 4096 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54344236), which basically precludes this option.

An alternative is to store the key files in a secure private bucket on AWS S3.
The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-storingprivatekeys.html) describes how to set up an IAM role that grants access to your S3 bucket for the EC2 instance. The documentation does provide a configuration example, but this uses `.ebextensions` and does not apply to `.platform` hooks.

In short, we can create a basic S3 bucket with default settings ("block public access" enabled, no custom permissions), and upload the SSH key files to that bucket.
Then, using the AWS IAM web console, select the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` (or, preferably, create a custom role), and attach the `AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy.

During deployment to Elastic Beanstalk, we can use `.platform` hooks to download the key files from the S3 bucket to the EC2 instance using the [aws cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

To test connectivity between EC2 and S3, we could use [eb ssh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html) to connect to the EC2 instance, followed by, for example, `aws s3 ls s3://<bucket name>` to list bucket contents.

#### Updating known_hosts

To indicate that bitbucket.org is a trusted host, its public key needs to be added to the `known_hosts` file on our instance.
In our platform hook script, we remove any existing public keys for the host, in case they are stale, and replace them by the current key from our file on S3:

```sh
SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE="/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
[ -f $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE ] && ssh-keygen -R $REPO_HOST_NAME
aws s3 cp "s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$REPO_HOST_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME" - >> $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE
```

#### Specifying the private key

The private key can be downloaded from S3 as follows, and we need to restrict the file permissions:

```sh
PRIVATE_KEY_FILE="/root/.ssh/$REPO_PRIVATE_KEY_NAME"
aws s3 cp "s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$REPO_PRIVATE_KEY_NAME" $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
chmod 600 $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
```

An SSH configuration file is also required to point to the private key:

```sh
tee $SSH_CONFIG_FILE <<HERE
Host $REPO_HOST_NAME
    User git
    Hostname $REPO_HOST_NAME
    IdentityFile $PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
HERE
chmod 600 $SSH_CONFIG_FILE
```

Again, file [permissions must be restricted](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#FILES).

The final script is shown in the summary at the top.
This script could be stored e.g. as `.platform/hooks/prebuild/01_configure_bitbucket_ssh.sh` in the project folder.

#### Hooks and confighooks

Note that Amazon Linux 2 uses `.platform/hooks`, for normal deployments, and `.platform/confighooks`, for configuration deployments.
Often, identical scripts need to be used in both cases.
To prevent duplication of code, our `.platform/confighooks/prebuild/01_configure_bitbucket_ssh.sh` could look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source "/var/app/current/.platform/hooks/prebuild/01_configure_bitbucket_ssh.sh"
```

Note that the application code ends up in `/var/app/current` on the instance.

Comment: The [AWS secrets manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/index.html) could provide an alternative to S3 for storing the keys.

Comment: To test SSH authentication, connect to your EC2 instance using `eb ssh` and then follow e.g. a guide like this: [Test SSH authentication](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/troubleshoot-ssh-issues/). If you're logged in as `ec2-user`, you need to use `sudo ssh ...` because the SSH keys are stored in `/root/.ssh`.

Comment: Note: Bitbucket host keys were recently updated, see https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76266042.